# Can share a SQL Compact Edition 3.5 database?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce

I made an application with SQL Compact Edition 3.5 to be used from many user but in the test I got can't connect to databse after the first one how connected !

this is an erreur in my application or probleme with many connexion in SDF file ?

and what about Compact Edition 3.5 accept 256 connexion!

Comment: SQL server CE is in-process single user

Comment: @Eugen Rieck : you say there's no why to let acces to database from multi PC to the same sdf file ! there's a lot of work to change :(

Comment: Why a lot of work, just upsize to SQL Server Express :-)

Comment: Actually it's quite easy: Use another SQL server edition - but make sure you understand the use-cases (connection limit, performance, licensing) first. Alternatively wrap SQL-CE in a homegrown server process which accepts, serialzes and executes the queries - again after udnerstanding the use-cases

Comment: @ErikEJ : this a part of a bigger project and this part designed to be with sdf file

Comment: @Eugen Rieck : I will read about the uses-cases (I don't have an idea about them )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look at a Microsoft [Locking in SQL Server CE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172975.aspx). In a nutshell, it says multi users/application can concurrently access the SDF at the same time provided the database is not locked in a transaction.

Also, I like to mentioned that we also do not have multi user/application access to a SQL Server CE 3.1 file on a network drive. (This constraint may still be true for SQL Server CE 3.5). If you're being affected by this, you will have to ensure your SDF is being opened using a local drive reference.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on how your application behaves, you might be able to replace SQL Compact with [SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/).  It can really only handle one write at a time but can handle multiple simultaneous reads.  Anything more than that and you should be looking at a real SQL server.